# List Item file attachment using ECMAScript Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, attachments

How to simply upload & attach file to listItem using Javascript? And how to get/download attachments.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own file control in HTML and hook it up with the below script. I use an asynchronous loop to iterate through the files (works in IE9).

```
//Enable Multiple Upload Script

$('.attachmentButton').change(function(event){  
//alert("change");  
//startUpload(self, function (){ reloadPage(); }, event);   
$("#WSOutput").html("<b>Please wait while files are getting attached. </b>");
 var listName = claimHeaderList; // change these to suit your list and item
 selectedFilesLength = event.target.files.length;
            asyncLoop({
    length : event.target.files.length+1,
    functionToLoop : function(loop, i){
        setTimeout(function(){
            //document.write('Iteration ' + i + ' <br>');

            handleFileChange(listName,itemId,event.target.files[i],i);
            loop();
        },10);
    },
    callback : function(){
    location.reload();
    //document.write('All done!');
    }    
});

});   


 });

 var asyncLoop = function(o){
    var i=-1;

    var loop = function(){
        i++;
        if(i==o.length){o.callback(); return;}
        o.functionToLoop(loop, i);
    } 
    loop();//init
}

 function handleFileChange(listName,itemId,file,length,_callback){
 //alert(length+"selectedFilesLength:" + selectedFilesLength );
 if( !(length==selectedFilesLength))
 {

 //alert(file.name);
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
 var getFileBuffer = function(file) {

  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
  }

  reader.onerror = function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
  }

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  return deferred.promise();
};
   getFileBuffer(file).then(function(buffer) {
  var binary = "";
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var i = bytes.byteLength;
  while (i--) {
    binary = String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]) + binary;
  }
  $("#WSOutput").html("<b>Please wait while files are getting attached. </b>").SPServices({
    operation: "AddAttachment",
    async: false,
    listName: listName,
    listItemID: itemId,
    fileName: file.name,
    attachment: btoa(binary),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //$("#WSOutput").html("");
                }
  });
}); 
//_callback(); 
}
```

---

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="attachmentButton" name="attachmentButton"/>
<div id="WSOutput"> &#160;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer from here:

[how to create a list item with attachment using Javascript object model](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/62d3f2db-f5fa-4770-b86b-081bf3280577/how-to-create-a-list-item-with-attachment-using-javascript-object-model?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: Please provide context for links and quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.